# adding data attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons being generated using the following two lines of jquery:

```
prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev">Previous</button>',
nextArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next">Next</button>',
```

I need to add the following data attribute to both  tags listed above.

```
data-ga-event='{"category":"Creamy-Delicious-Mashed-Potatoes", "action":"Ingredients", "label":"Get-Nutrition-Info"}'
```

I tried just pasting it after `data-role="none"` but it was causing a 404 error message when I clicked on the button. I think its related to the quotation marks. Thanks ahead of time for your help.

Comment: Show your attempt, please.

Comment: nothing in code shown would cause a 404 even with the `data-ga-event` included in strings

Comment: This is what I tried to replace the jquery line with, but it caused a 404 error message when I clicked on the button. nextArrow:'<button type="button" data-role="none" data-ga-event="{"category":"Creamy-Delicious-Mashed-Potatoes", "action":"How-to-Videos", "label":"Right-Nav"}" class="slick-next">Next</button>'

Comment: ahh my bad, you would need to escape double quotes in the JSON string

Comment: do you mean this? If so I tried that and it messed up the whole carousel :( data-ga-event='{\"category\":\"Creamy-Delicious-Mashed-Potatoes\", \"action\":\"How-to-Videos\", \"label\":\"Left-Nav\"}'

Answer (score 0):

You could do by setting the data as an object and then using JSON.stringify to concatenate with as it would escape all the quotes:

```
var data = {
    "category": "Creamy-Delicious-Mashed-Potatoes",
    "action": "Ingredients",
    "label": "Get-Nutrition-Info"
} 

prevArrow: '<button data-ga-event="' + JSON.stringify(data) +'" >Previous</button>',
```